# Sonar taking too much space and time

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am new to Sonar and trying to configure it to work on my project correctly after an upgrade that was done by some one else.
We upgraded our Sonar server from 3.x version to 5.0.1 version. After some configuration management we made it to run successfully but now each build is taking like 2.5 GB of DB disk space and taking like 2 hours. Previously it was not taking that much time. Previously, (I do not know what the config was like), the issues raised by Sonar was like in hundreds but now it is like 2 million.

Where could be the issue. I tried searching for this but did not find much. I am guessing that it is analyzing files that it was not previously like generated files or generated js files.

I am using java 7, and gwt which does generate some JS files. Where can i look to filter the files for analysis. The Sonar is running through Jenkins which is run during a maven project job. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Sonar click on the violations, you should be able to see the list of files analysed for violations. Also a simple check could be on the LOC reported from your previous and current analysis.

Also check the values against sonar.sources property

Comment: Thanks, Is there a way to see which test is taking too much time and when I know which files are being analyze uselessly how do i turn it off for them.

Comment: If your running test goal also from Jenkins, then there are plugins in Jenkins to report the UT results though which we can identify which test case took maximum time. Also there are options in sonar to exclude file - http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Answer (score 0):

I would recommand that you have a look (or publish here) the Jenkins log specific to the SonarQube job on your application. 
Maybe the 'upgrade' has added some more plugins that are responsible of the delay. 
Or have added new rules to the Quality Profile you are using. So I would recommand you check it and deactivate rules that are not pertinent for you.

Anyway, more info on your configuration (DB, local/server install, etc.) would be helpfull, before to look for changes in your code/application like generated files.

Regards.